# call recording on samsung phones(TAB 2)

Tags: call, recording

I have been working on a call recorder app which is working fine on MEDIATEK(XOLO, Micromax etc) phones and Sony Xperia SP.
But Samsung is giving me nightmares. I have tried two samsung phones specifically Galaxy Tab2 and one I don't remember name of(let me know if you want to know).

Can anyone tell what settings are needed for Samsung. I have used these:

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);      
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
```

I have tried almost all the combinations of every audio source VOICE_COMMUNICATION, VOICE_CALL, DEFAULT, MIC etc with every audio format and every audio encoder namely 3gpp, mp4, AMR_NB, AMR_WB etc.

I have read many forums regarding this problem but most of them are either unsatisfactory or too old to consider.